# MS Excel 2016 Copy row(s) to a second sheet based on result of formulas

Tags: excel, array-formulas

I have an activity log on a sheet called DISPATCH LOG that tracks the assignments of multiple people. I have an array formula:

```
{=MAX(IF(OFFICERS=M251,ROW(OFFICERS)-ROW(INDEX(OFFICERS,1,1))+1))}
```

that shows the last assignment of a person. There is one formula like the one above for each person that is logged. `OFFICERS` is a named range from column `F1:F250`.

I would like to have the row from the result of the formula copied to a second sheet that would show the last or current assignment for each person in the log.

Is there a way to do this that would work in Excel and be compatible with Excel Online?

Answer (score 0):

Is the assignment in a specific column? Assuming column B then this formula will find the last assignment for `M251`

`=LOOKUP(2,1/(F$1:F$250=M251),B$1:B$250)`

change references as required